# Excel VBA Error on my Msgbox line

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting an Application-defined or object-defined error on my Msgbox line. I have both InputBox variables declared as String. I tried changing Sheets(sheetname1) to an actual sheet name but same error. I tried everything I know, I'm puzzled with this error. Any help is appreciated.

```
sheetname1 = Application.InputBox("Enter the name of your first sheet.")
sheetname2 = Application.InputBox("Enter the name of your second sheet.")
For i = 1 To 100
    For j = 1 To 100
        If Not Sheets(sheetname1).Cells(i, j).Value = Sheets(sheetname2).Cells(i, j).Value Then
            Sheets(sheetname1).Select
            Cells(i, j).Select
            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 65535
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
            ans = MsgBox("Cells " & i & "," & j & " do not match." & vbNewLine & "The value on " & sheetname1 & " is " & Sheets(sheetname1).Cells(i, j).Value & " and the value on " & sheetname2 & " is " & Sheets("sheetname2").Cells(i, j).Value, vbOKCancel + vbQuestion)
            If ans = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
            Else
                GoTo skip1
        End If
skip1:
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Cells(i1, j1)`? That's where your issue is.  Should that just be `Cells(i,j)`?  Or `Cells(i & 1, j & 1)`?

Comment: Thanks @BruceWayne, you got a great eye! It's suppose to be Cells(i,j). One quick question, how do you type the blue highlighted code type text in comments?

Comment: @BruceWayne ok, I'm done doing this. Next time *you* post answers as answers and then I can stop feeling like I'm stealing your checkmarks =)

Comment: @Mat'sMug - haha, I don't mind at all!

Comment: I corrected my code and everything works great. Thank you both!

Comment: The best *thank you* you can give on Stack Overflow is an upvote; also, consider marking the answer as *the* answer by clicking the checkmark next to it, that will remove this question from the gigantic pool of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@BruceWayne correctly identified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978119/excel-vba-error-on-my-msgbox-line#comment63402314_37978119), you're using undeclared variables. Use `Option Explicit`.

Let me rephrase that...

## ALWAYS use Option Explicit

Simple: stick the words `Option Explicit` at the top of *every single module* you ever see, and VBA will refuse to compile code where you're using an undeclared variable.

In this instance, you're referring to `i1` and `j1`, which both contain the non-value `Empty`, since they're undeclared and uninitialized variants.

Here are the variables you need to declare:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim ans As vbMsgBoxResult
Dim sheetName1 As String
Dim sheetName2 As String
```

Without `Option Explicit`, VBA happily compiles a typo and takes it as "oh, I've never seen that guy, must be a new variable!"

Comment: Yes! Best practice! Nice answer amigo.  (Fun fact: you can use `Dim myVar&`  for `Dim myVar as Long`, and `Dim myString$` for `Dim myString as String`).